# Assimp not reading texture coordinate information from a ply file

Tags: textures, game-engine, mesh, assimp

I am trying to load some ply files with assimp. I am getting the vertex locations and the normals are also loading properly (I see them appear onscreen so all good) however it seems that the texture coordinates never get loaded in. This causes the the textures not to appear on the models and my diffuse colours to appear on them instead of the texture.

I have looked through my code and found that the issue is in the assimp loader class I have made. mTextureCoords[0][index] is completely null.

I have tried changing the if around the texture coords being assigned but I believe that is correct?

Here is a snippet of the loader method that contains the code to get the texture coords

```
    if (scene->HasMeshes()) {   //Check to see if the filename was valid

        aiMesh* aiMesh = *scene->mMeshes;

        theMesh.numberOfVertices = aiMesh->mNumVertices;

        //Create the number of vertices that this mesh has.
        theMesh.pVertices = new sVertex_xyz_rgba_n_uv2_bt[theMesh.numberOfVertices];

        theMesh.minXYZ.x = aiMesh->mVertices[0].x;
        theMesh.minXYZ.y = aiMesh->mVertices[0].y;
        theMesh.minXYZ.z = aiMesh->mVertices[0].z;

        theMesh.maxXYZ = theMesh.minXYZ;

        for (unsigned int index = 0; index != theMesh.numberOfVertices; index++) {
            theMesh.pVertices[index].x = aiMesh->mVertices[index].x;
            theMesh.pVertices[index].y = aiMesh->mVertices[index].y;
            theMesh.pVertices[index].z = aiMesh->mVertices[index].z;

            if (theMesh.pVertices[index].x < theMesh.minXYZ.x) { theMesh.minXYZ.x = theMesh.pVertices[index].x; }
            if (theMesh.pVertices[index].y < theMesh.minXYZ.y) { theMesh.minXYZ.y = theMesh.pVertices[index].y; }
            if (theMesh.pVertices[index].z < theMesh.minXYZ.z) { theMesh.minXYZ.z = theMesh.pVertices[index].z; }

            if (theMesh.pVertices[index].x > theMesh.maxXYZ.x) { theMesh.maxXYZ.x = theMesh.pVertices[index].x; }
            if (theMesh.pVertices[index].y > theMesh.maxXYZ.y) { theMesh.maxXYZ.y = theMesh.pVertices[index].y; }
            if (theMesh.pVertices[index].z > theMesh.maxXYZ.z) { theMesh.maxXYZ.z = theMesh.pVertices[index].z; }


            theMesh.pVertices[index].nx = aiMesh->mNormals[index].x;
            theMesh.pVertices[index].ny = aiMesh->mNormals[index].y;
            theMesh.pVertices[index].nz = aiMesh->mNormals[index].z;


            int numUVComponents = aiMesh->mNumUVComponents[0];

            if (numUVComponents == 2) {
                theMesh.pVertices[index].u1 = aiMesh->mTextureCoords[0][index].x;
                theMesh.pVertices[index].v1 = aiMesh->mTextureCoords[0][index].y;
            }
        }

        theMesh.numberOfTriangles = scene->mMeshes[0]->mNumFaces;
        theMesh.pTriangles = new cTriangle[theMesh.numberOfTriangles];

        //Copy the triangle vertex information (indices)
        for (int triIndex = 0; triIndex != theMesh.numberOfTriangles; triIndex++) {
            theMesh.pTriangles[triIndex].vertex_ID_0 = aiMesh->mFaces[triIndex].mIndices[0];
            theMesh.pTriangles[triIndex].vertex_ID_1 = aiMesh->mFaces[triIndex].mIndices[1];
            theMesh.pTriangles[triIndex].vertex_ID_2 = aiMesh->mFaces[triIndex].mIndices[2];
        }
    }
```

and here is a snippet of the model file I am attempting to load with assimp with the header and few lines of the vertices, normals, and uvs.

```
ply
format ascii 1.0
comment VCGLIB generated
element vertex 289
property float x
property float y
property float z
property float nx
property float ny
property float nz
property float texture_u
property float texture_v
element face 512
property list uchar int vertex_indices
end_header
-400 1.748456e-05 400 0 0.25 -1.092785e-08 1.000000 0.000000
-350 1.748456e-05 400 0 0.25 -1.092785e-08 1.000000 0.062500
-300 1.748456e-05 400 0 0.25 -1.092785e-08 1.000000 0.125000
-250 1.748456e-05 400 0 0.25 -1.092785e-08 1.000000 0.187500
-200 1.748456e-05 400 0 0.25 -1.092785e-08 1.000000 0.250000
-150 1.748456e-05 400 0 0.25 -1.092785e-08 1.000000 0.312500
-100 1.748456e-05 400 0 0.25 -1.092785e-08 1.000000 0.375000
-50 1.748456e-05 400 0 0.25 -1.092785e-08 1.000000 0.437500
```

Hopefully someone knows where I am messing up =) 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Still a little unsure why assimp cannot load the ply. But I confirmed that my code works for FBX files. maybe assimp is not compatible with this style?